# Error while Uploading file to FTP server C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, stream, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to upload a .txt file to a ftp server. But i am having some issues. I keep getting this error: **The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed.**

This always happens on this line:

```
Stream writer = ftpReq.GetRequestStream();
```

I cant figure out what the problem is. I have tried uploading the file with filezilla and that works fine. I also have tried to copy the file destination url from the server and harcode it into my application, but i still get the same error. Is there any other ways of uploading a file to a ftp server??

this is my code:

```
string localFilePath = @"\\fileprint\data\Groups\Operation\fileExports\folder\";
string archiveFilePath = @"\\fileprint\data\Groups\Operation\fileExports\folder\Archive\";
string logFilePath = @"C:\Users\lmy\Desktop\Logs";
string ftpServer = "ftp://my.server.no:21/home/pll332/tmp/";
private string logFileName = "" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
string userName = "pll332";
string password = "password";

public Controller()
{
}

public void UploadFile()
{
    try
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(localFilePath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpServer + fileName));
            ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpReq.UsePassive = true;
            ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
            ftpReq.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName.Normalize(), password.Normalize());

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localFilePath + @"\" + fileName);
            FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

            byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileInfo.Length];
            fileStream.Read(fileContent, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileInfo.Length));

            Stream writer = ftpReq.GetRequestStream();
            writer.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
            writer.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();

            AppendLogFile(response, "Uploaded Files: ", fileName);
            MoveToArchive(file, archiveFilePath + fileName);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me. thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have tried this:

```
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder();
            uri.Scheme = "ftp";
            uri.Host = "my.server.no";
            uri.Port = 21;
            uri.Path = "/home/username/tmp/";
            uri.UserName = "username";
            uri.Password = "password";
            FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri.ToString() + fileName));
            ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpReq.UsePassive = true;
            ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
            ftpReq.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName.Normalize(), password.Normalize());
```

This gives me the same error......

Comment: You may try to use third party components such as http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/

Comment: What did you try? What is the actual value of `ftpServer + fileName` when you get the error?

Comment: `ftp://my.server.no:21/home/username/tmp/01002589006741.TXT` this is the value of ftpserver+filename. After using UriBuilder it looks like this. `ftp://username:password@my.server.no:21/home/username/tmp/01002589006741.TXT` stille getting the same error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the reason for the error. It seems that the server i was trying to upload to was a linux server. I found a description in a forum of how to fix the issue. And this is was was written in the forum:

**This may help for Linux FTP server.**

So, Linux FTP servers unlike IIS don't have common FTP root directory. Instead, when you log on to FTP server under some user's credentials, this user's root directory is used. So FTP directory hierarchy starts from /root/ for root user and from /home/username for others.
So, if you need to query a file not relative to user account home directory, but relative to file system root, add an extra `/` after server name. Resulting URL will look like:

`ftp://servername.net//var/lalala`

so when i changed my connection Uri from:

```
ftp://username:password@my.server.no:21/home/username/tmp/
```

to:

```
ftp://username:password@my.server.no:21//home/username/tmp/
```

(notice i have added an extra **/** before **/home/username/tmp/**)

then i worked!!